# Is there a simple way to randomly select a sub-set of case from a larger data set based on a specified unit-size?

Tags: dataset, random-generation

I have a very large data set consisting of individual cases. Each individual case is associated with a unit-level id number indicating the group to which the individual case belongs to. So, there can be multiple individual cases associated with the same unit. The unit sizes can range anywhere from 2 to infinity. I am interested only in units ranging from 5 to 20 individuals.

My question: Using the original individual-level data set, is there a way to randomly select a specified number of units (let’s say 200) within my specified unit size range of 5 to 20. In other words, I want all the individual observations associated with 200 randomly selected unit identifiers that range in frequency from 5 to 20.

Preferably, I was hoping to find a way to do this simply with R-code or SPSS syntax. I’ve had zero luck searching through R and IBM webpages, FAQs, forums, etc. I found a roundabout way to do this via data sorting by frequency in excel, but requires multiple steps moving tons of data across software. Kind of annoying. Anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in R using dplyr.

First we get a list of the units that meet your size requirement and pick 200 of them. Where "unit" is the grouping variable:

```
library(dplyr)

selected_units <- raw_data %>%
  group_by(unit) %>%
  summarise(unit_size = n()) %>%
  filter(unit_size >= 5 & unit_size <= 20) %>%
  select(unit) %>%
  sample_n(size = 200)
```

Now, use the original data to grab all individual rows from the selected units:

```
selected_data <- raw_data %>% 
  filter(unit %in% selected_units$unit)
```